# Calculate Adjacent Powerset of an array

Tags: algorithm, powerset

Internet is [full of powerset algorithms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array).

But in my case, I need only powerset of adjacent parts.

Eg. From: `[1, 2, 3]`, I'd need to get:

```
adjacentPowerset([1, 2, 3]) = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1], [2], [3]];
// Without [1, 3]
```

I'm struggling to achieve this...

A functional solution would be much appreciated (eventually recursive).

Comment: Adjacent parts.. so, all ranges?

Comment: Why is `[2, 3]` adjacent to `[1]`?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I guess the order does not matter.

Comment: `[2, 3]` is adjacent in the sense that they are consecutive. `[1, 3]` isn't because in an ordered array, `2` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-empty range looks like `xs[i:j]` where `i<j`.

You can use nested loops for this:

```
def adj_powerset(xs):
    for i in xrange(len(xs)):
        for j in xrange(i, len(xs)):
            yield xs[i:j+1]

print list(adj_powerset([1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: Awesome, your answer is the clearest. Here's my [LoDash](https://lodash.com/) 100% functional version: `_.flatten(_.map(_.range(0, array.length), function(i){ return _.map(_.range(i, array.length), function(j){ return _.slice(array, i, j+1); }); }))` Not really readable I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sliding windows to solve this problem:

python code:

```
def adjacent_powerset(arr):
    result = []

    #loop over all possible lengths of subarrays
    for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):  
        #loop over all possible starting indices of subarrays of length i
        for j in range(1, len(arr) - i + 1):
            #store subarray at position j with length i in the powerset
            result.append(arr[j:j+i])

    return result
```

Test-run:

```
print adjacent_powerset([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

produces

> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

If you prefer order from largest to smallest subset, you have to replace this line:

```
for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
```

by

```
for i in range(len(arr) , 0, -1):
```

The basic idea would be that all subarrays of a specific length `l` can be generated using a sliding window of length `l` and copying the content of the sliding window to the result, while moving over the array.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution in Python -

```
st = set()

arr = [1, 2, 3]

res = list()

def power_set(i, j):
    if i == j:
        return
    if (i, j) not in st:
        res.append(arr[i : j])
    power_set(i, j - 1)
    power_set(i + 1, j)
    st.add((i, j))

power_set(0, len(arr))

print(res)
```

Output -

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: My solution is still somewhat buggy. I'll fix it soon.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for the other answer as I find it more readable, but yours should definitely work.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You're right. I tried to write a recursive solution as you asked but other answers are easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: I asked in case there was no better solution. Cheers